# Flask App with Pandas works differently in development mode or with gunicorn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flask, gunicorn

I have to compare two temperature dataframes and give it to the user using flask.
My datas are in a MariaDb database.

So the request Get that I receive is the two temperature to compare, the start_date , end_date and a comparaison value

When I receive the GET Request in flask I create a first dataframe for the first temperature and I create a second dataframe for the second temperature

```
import flask
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

# engine creation 
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:pass@localhost/db",    echo=True)
conn_sql_alchemy = engine.connect()

# function to create dataframe for
def create_dataframe(obj, start_date, end_date):
    # with obj, start_date and end_date I create a request like this one
    sql_sp_query = text("select  timestamp, value from db.tldata where pointId = (select Id from db.device_pointList where DeviceId = ( select Id from db.device where device_instance =200) and  ObjectId = 9 and object='trendLog') and timestamp between '2019-10-30 00:00:00' and '2019-10-31 23:59:59'")
    #creation of dataframe
    pd_datas = pd.read_sql_query(sql_sp_query, conn_sql_alchemy, index_col="timestamp")
    # return dataframe
    return pd_datas

# flask route
@app.route('/analyse_co/<object_sp>/<object_ai>/<start_date>/<end_date>/<difference>')
def analyse_co(object_sp, object_ai, start_date, end_date, difference):
    print('creation of dataframe for object_ai')
    pd_ai_datas = create_dataframe(object_ai, start_date, end_date)
    print(pd_ai_datas)
    print('creation of dataframe for object_sp')
    pd_sp_datas = create_dataframe(object_sp, start_date, end_date)
    print(pd_sp_datas)
    return 'finish'
```

When I try my app in development mode I get the result that I'm waiting
I get my two dataframe printed on console and see finish on the web page

Result on console :

    `creation of dataframe for object_ai
    2019-11-08 08:34:32,113 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select  timestamp, value from db.tldata where pointId = (select Id from db.device_pointList where DeviceId = ( select Id from db.device where device_instance =200) and  ObjectId = 7 and object='trendLog') and timestamp between '2019-10-30 00:00:00' and '2019-10-31 23:59:59'
    2019-11-08 08:34:32,114 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
    timestamp              value
    2019-10-30 00:00:00  10.475613
    2019-10-30 00:15:00   8.461939
    2019-10-30 00:30:00   5.507755
    2019-10-30 00:45:00   8.461939
    2019-10-30 01:00:00   5.507755
    ...                        ...
    2019-10-31 22:45:00  10.641429
    2019-10-31 23:00:00   1.556020
    2019-10-31 23:15:00  11.016837
    2019-10-31 23:30:00   8.576020
    2019-10-31 23:45:00   9.379898
    [192 rows x 1 columns]
    creation of dataframe for object_sp
    2019-11-08 08:34:32,222 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select  timestamp, value from db.tldata where pointId = (select Id from db.device_pointList where DeviceId = ( select Id from db.device where device_instance =200) and  ObjectId = 9 and object='trendLog') and timestamp between '2019-10-30 00:00:00' and '2019-10-31 23:59:59'
    2019-11-08 08:34:32,223 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
    timestamp              value
    2019-10-30 00:00:00  14.265137
    2019-10-30 00:15:00  15.733887
    2019-10-30 00:30:00  17.308594
    2019-10-30 00:45:00  18.942383
    2019-10-30 01:00:00  20.517090
    ...                          ...
    2019-10-31 22:45:00  03.228516
    2019-10-31 23:00:00  04.716309
    2019-10-31 23:15:00  06.372070
    2019-10-31 23:30:00  07.834961
    2019-10-31 23:45:00  09.363281
    [192 rows x 1 columns]
    10.23.1.41 - - [08/Nov/2019 08:34:32] "GET /analyse_co/200.tl9/200.tl7/2019-10-30/2019-10-31/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

When I try my app using nginx and gunicorn in HTTPS, on the log I just see the creation of my first dataframe, the second is ignored, and I do not have error on my web page, I see finish...

`Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: creation of dataframe for object_ai
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-11-08 08:35:04,050 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select  timestamp, value from db.tldata where pointId = (select Id from db.device_pointList where DeviceId = ( select Id from db.device where device_instance =200) and  ObjectId = 7 and object='trendLog') and timestamp between '2019-10-30 00:00:00' and '2019-10-31 23:59:59'
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-11-08 08:35:04,050 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]:                          value
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: timestamp
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-10-30 00:00:00  10.475613
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-10-30 00:15:00   8.461939
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-10-30 00:30:00   5.507755
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-10-30 00:45:00   8.461939
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-10-30 01:00:00   5.507755
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: ...                        ...
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-10-31 22:45:00  10.641429
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-10-31 23:00:00   1.556020
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-10-31 23:15:00  11.016837
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-10-31 23:30:00   8.576020
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-10-31 23:45:00   9.379898
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: [192 rows x 1 columns]
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: creation of dataframe for object_sp
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-11-08 08:35:04,187 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select  timestamp, value from db.tldata where pointId = (select Id from db.device_pointList where DeviceId = ( select Id from db.device where device_instance =200) and  ObjectId = 9 and object='trendLog') and timestamp between '2019-10-30 00:00:00' and '2019-10-31 23:59:59'
    Nov  8 08:35:04 rockpro64 gunicorn[24608]: 2019-11-08 08:35:04,187 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}`

Comment: My guess would be the database you're connecting to when you're using Gunicorn doesn't have the same data as your development one.

Comment: No it's the same database... I run development or production on the same server.

Comment: I ask because in the top code it mentions `nbox.tldata` whereas the bottom code mentions `db.tldata`

Comment: Oups I forgot to change when I copy paste on stackOverflow. It s really the same database. I will edit.

Comment: So I found that the last dataframes is not printing but it's here. I can do some comparaison with.